# Necessary & sufficient condition on the bases for two topologies on a space $X$ to be the same.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find a necessary & sufficient condition on the bases for two topologies on a space $X$ to be the same. 
Would I be correct in thinking that two topologies both on the same space are the same if and only if their minimal cardinality bases are the same?

Comment: What do you mean by minimal cardinality bases?

Comment: The smallest bases for the topologies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. $\Bbb R$ has a countable basis, consisting of $\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$. It also has another countable basis, consisting of $\{(a+\sqrt2,b+\sqrt2)\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$. These are not the same.

Comment: Of minimum cardinality or weight.

Comment: I'm trying to find a condition on the bases of the two topologies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality of cardinality of bases that have minimal cardinality is not enough.

Take $X=\{1,2,3\}$ as underlying set.

Then $\mathcal V_1:=\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\mathcal V_2:=\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ are bases of the distinct topologies $\tau_1:=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $\tau_2:=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\},\{3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ respectively.

Evidently both topologies do not have a base with smaller cardinality.

---

Two bases $\mathcal V_1$ and $\mathcal V_2$ induce the same topolology if and only if for every $B\in\mathcal V_1$ and every $x\in B$ you can find a $C\in\mathcal V_2$ with $x\in C\subseteq B$ and vice versa.

Comment: Consider the simpler condition: Iff for every $B\in\mathcal V_1$ there is a $C\in\mathcal V_2$ with $C\subseteq B$ and vice versa. Is this equivalent?

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus I am afraid not. E.g. take the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ (induced by open intervals) and the topology that have the intervals of the form $(a,b]$ as basis. Then your simpler condition is satisfied, but the topologies are not the same.